# Why isn't prometheus cloudwatch metrics exporter pod accessing my aws role and working?

Tags: debugging, prometheus, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-eks

I've been trying for a few days to get prometheus-cloudwatch-exporter to work in my eks cluster but i've exhuasted all debugging option.
The pod doesn't write to my prometheus db. I've narrowed it down and I can see that the exporter pod isn't using my assigned aws role(as seen by my access logs).
I've successfully got this to work in my ECS cluster with no problems.
If I shell into the exporter pod, install aws cli and get metrics manually it returns the correct values so the pod has the correct sts token to use.
The pod just seems to sit thier doing nothing. No error logs.

Using helm to manage but even tried to install manually to debug it.

**Pod logs:**

```
Nov 09, 2023 1:52:39 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server doStart
INFO: jetty-11.0.15; built: 2023-04-11T18:37:53.775Z; git: 5bc5e562c8d05c5862505aebe5cf83a61bdbcb96; jvm 17.0.7+7
Nov 09, 2023 1:52:39 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler doStart
INFO: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@32057e6{/,null,AVAILABLE}
Nov 09, 2023 1:52:39 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector doStart
INFO: Started ServerConnector@47db5fa5{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:9106}
Nov 09, 2023 1:52:39 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server doStart
INFO: Started Server@21005f6c{STARTING}[11.0.15,sto=0] @1898ms
Nov 09, 2023 2:32:42 PM io.prometheus.cloudwatch.CloudWatchCollector reloadConfig
```

**image**

```
image:
  repository: prom/cloudwatch-exporter
  # if not set appVersion field from Chart.yaml is used
  tag: v0.15.4
```

**kubernetes version** 1.25

I can provide additional information on IAM policy, config, SA, mounts etc but as I said, its all looking correct and when I shell into the pod it has correct access permissions.
The JVM is running when I look at the threads. The app logs aren't very verbose.
When I compare them to the working task in my ECS cluster they are exactly the same. ie no indication of when it makes a request to AWS cli api

Has anyone else experienced this before? is there something i'm missing from the docs and init?

Thanks